# Rails, trying to create a specific hash, but it does not work the way it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every **area** has multiple **area_attachments**.

For some reason I want only the images to be saved into the hash into the following way

```
@area_hash =[]
@aa_hash=[]

      @areas.each_with_index do |area, counter|
          @area_hash[counter] = {}
          @area_hash[counter][:localizations] = area.article_localizations

          area.area_attachments.each_with_index do |aa, i| 
              @aa_hash[i]={}           
              @full = aa.image.full.url
              @large_thumb = aa.image.large_thumb.url
              @thumb = aa.image.thumb.url
              @aa_hash[i] = {full: @full, large_thumb: @large_thumb, thumb: @thumb}
          end

          @area_hash[counter][:images] = @aa_hash
      end
```

The problem is the **@area_hash[counter][:images]** is the same at every area. having the attachments of the first area.

I know something is wrong with my loop, but I can't find out what exactly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@area_hash =[]

@areas.each_with_index do |area, counter|
    @area_hash[counter] = {}
    @area_hash[counter][:localizations] = area.article_localizations

    @area_hash[counter][:images] = []

    area.area_attachments.each_with_index do |aa, i| 
        @full = aa.image.full.url
        @large_thumb = aa.image.large_thumb.url
        @thumb = aa.image.thumb.url
        @area_hash[counter][:images] << {full: @full, large_thumb: @large_thumb, thumb: @thumb}
    end
end
```